# Is there a conflict between the xkeyval and alterqcm packages?

Tags: xkeyval, alterqcm

When I try to compile the code for this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39517/138900) or its [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39904/138900), I have an error. A year ago, I didn't have that mistake.

> Package xkeyval Error: `language' undefined in families`global'.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm,language=english] 
 \AQquestion{Question}{% 
 {Proposition 1},
 {Proposition 2},
 {Proposition 3}}  
\end{alterqcm}

\end{document}
```

What's the problem now?

Comment: the language support seems to have been moved to package options so `\usepackage[english]{alterqcm}` or `\usepackage[french{alterqcm}` separately you also need to define `\square `and `\nogreekalph` (to anything) then it runs and gives what I think is the intended result.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this issue.  When I pass the language option to the package `\usepackage[language=english]{alterqcm}` I get this error: `LaTeX Error: Unknown option "language=english" for package "alterqcm".`
For `\square` and `\nogreekalph`, I didn't understand what to do.

Comment: `\square` you can define by loading `amssymb` if you are not using Greek you can define `\nogreekalph` to be anything `\def\nogreekalph{}` I think, You should raise both issues (and the incompatible language syntax), with the package maintainers. the new syntax is `\usepackage[english]{alterqcm}` not `\usepackage[language=english]{alterqcm}`

Comment: `alterqcm` being written by a Frenchman, I don't need the language option. As for the rest, with the code you gave in the chat, it works. I don't know why, but the main thing is there, it works.

Comment: There i a new version. The package has been modified by Apostolos Syropoulos and Anastasios Dimou . I do not know exactly what has changed because I do not have much time; I'm trying to finish my work on tkz-euclide. The alterqcm package  has been modified so that one can use it when
preparing Greek language documents.

Comment: @AlainMatthes The latest version of alterqcm is 4.1 which dates from June 24, 2019. This version gives the error I indicated here. I wrote about a month ago by email to the new developers and they haven't answered me yet. Currently, Ulrike Fisher's correction to this question is working: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511601/138900

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the solution given later to another question makes it possible to resolve it:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511601/138900

Comment: @AndréC Great AndréC: the base is the humilty.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is essential to close this issue so that future users who encounter this problem can be referred to an existing solution. This is necessary for the proper functioning of tex.stackexchange.