# How to reduce the spacing between responses in the alterqcm package?

Tags: alterqcm

This question has a continuation here [How to reduce the spacing between responses in True/False MCQs of the alterqcm package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593496/138900)

---

The `alterqcm` package is no longer maintained by Alain Matthes. Two other developers maintain it. I wrote to them 15 days ago by email to report the error reported here: [Is there a conflict between the xkeyval and alterqcm packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510290/is-there-a-conflict-between-the-xkeyval-and-alterqcm-packages)
I have not received a reply.

I am trying to reduce the spacing between the lines of the QCM as indicated in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39904/138900) by @Werner and it does not work.

In addition, by using the David Carlisle's code given in [the chat](http://.https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51883308#51883308), I get an X instead of a square.

[image: screenshot]

Full code of the screenshot:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage[english]{alterqcm}
\def\square{X} % <---------- David Carlisle comment
\def\nogreekalph{??} % <---- David Carlisle comment
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
% Original display
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Question}{%
 {Proposition 1},
 {Proposition 2},
 {Proposition 3}}
\end{alterqcm}

\bigskip

% Smashed display !!!!!! Dont work now 
{\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Question}{%
 {\smash{Proposition 1}},
 {\smash{Proposition 2}},
 {\smash{Proposition 3}}}
\end{alterqcm}}

\bigskip

% Global smashed display !!!! Dont work now 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\aq@prop}{\vbox{#1}}{\vbox{\smash{#1}}}{}{}% patch \aq@prop
\makeatother
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Question}{%
 {Proposition 1},
 {Proposition 2},
 {Proposition 3}}
\end{alterqcm}

\end{document}
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the \square command to whatever you want. The X from David was only a placeholder.

The extra spacing is hard coded, so to change it you will have to patch an internal command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,tikzducks}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage[english]{alterqcm}

\def\square{\tikz[scale=0.2]\duck;} %
\def\nogreekalph{??} % 
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aqheightadvance{4pt}
\newcommand\aqdepthadvance{3pt}
\patchcmd \aq@prop {4pt}{\aqheightadvance}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd \aq@prop {3pt}{\aqdepthadvance}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Question}{%
 {Proposition 1},
 {Proposition 2},
 {Proposition 3}}
\end{alterqcm}

\bigskip

\renewcommand\aqheightadvance{0pt}
\renewcommand\aqdepthadvance{0pt}

\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Question}{%
 {Proposition 1},
 {Proposition 2},
 {Proposition 3}}
\end{alterqcm}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this issue. If I understand your solution correctly, it is no longer necessary to use the `\smash` macro?

Comment: Imho \smash was never right but at best a work-around.

Comment: I really like your solution which greatly simplifies the coding of my MCQs. Indeed, until now only the solution with `\smash` worked correctly to reduce this space.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems to me that you forgot a `\makeatother` command

Comment: yes, I always forgot them. Added now.